# Why webdriver waits longer than defined time on implicit wait?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

I'm starting a new course about automation/testing with selenium/web driver in Java.
For testing purposes we have a python web application (using flask) that is just a basic CRUD of entries/posts of an imaginary blog.

During explanation of implicit and explicit waits, the example was to insert a new entry and wait for a success message using implicit wait.
Given the fact that the flask app is running locally it is not slow enough to test waits. So, the professor put an "time.sleep()" in the response method so it can take longer to return the message.

This is an extract of the response method:

```
elapsed_time=randint(10,12)
time.sleep(elapsed_time)
flash("Entry '" + entry.title + "' created successfully." + str(elapsed_time), "success")
```

And in the setup method of our testing class:

```
@Before
public void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\ChromeDriver\\chromedriver.exe");
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("localhost:5000");
}
```

This of course will work, because the implicit wait is set to 15 second and the app will take no longer than 12 seconds to respond.

The problem is that if I set the wait to 1 second, it still works, and even if i delete the entire line, it still works. (no error about not finding the element is thrown)

I asked the professor about why this is not failing and why keeps waiting more than the implicit wait I set (1 second), and he was not sure. He mentioned that he thinks there is some default time somewhere but didn't give me any precision.

**So, why if I set the implicit wait to 1 second it doesn't fail when trying to find the message?**

**I am missing something?**

The code to find the message is:

```
    String currentMessage = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/span")).getText();
    System.out.println(currentMessage);

    assertTrue(currentMessage.contains("Entry 'My newest post' created successfully."));
```

Comment: Can you paste the code of the `flash` method - just to confirm that it is adding to the dom, as opposed to simply making something visible.

Comment: Are you positively sure that your possibly ambiguous XPath expression does not match prematurely?

Comment: Implicit waits are only used when searching for elements.  You also have to bear in mind that by default selenium will try and load the page before it interacts with it, this will result in (at a very basic level) it waiting for `document.readyState` to be true.  If all elements have loaded on your page by the time `document.readyState` is set to true then there will be no delay finding any element and therefore the implicit wait is not needed hence no errors

Answer (score 0):

How much time does it take to load your page completely? Maybe your page was not loaded completely. Try to set both waits to 1 sec and give it a try.

1. Set page timeout to 1 sec.

   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
2. Set implicit wait to 1 sec.

   driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);